# Splitting a string into two strings in xquery

Tags: xquery

Here is the string

```
a = "http://www.peoples.net/mcfnet/viewtopic.php?f=143&amp;t=4898958&amp;sid=2110d616dbad926"
```

Now, we need to split this string into two and need a single string.

expected output is:

```
b = "http://www.peoples.net/mcfnet/viewtopic.php?f=143&amp;t=4898958&amp;"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the substring function

I think with the substring-before-match you can do what you want, or try take a look on the other substring's function.Check this [link](http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/xq/functx_substring-before-match.html).

Comment: Tnx a lot this helps me move forward.

Answer (score 0):

You want to get all of the original string except the last query-string parameter.

**Here is a single XPath 2.0 expression to produce this string from the original**, which is defined in a variable named `$vA`:

```
 codepoints-to-string
        (
         reverse
           (string-to-codepoints
                (substring-after
                    (codepoints-to-string
                        (reverse(string-to-codepoints($vA))
                     ),
                   '&amp;'
                 )
            )
          )
        )
```

**Explanation**:

1. We turn the string into a sequence of characters using `string-to-codepoints()` and reverse this sequence using `reverse()`. Then we turn the reversed sequence of characters back to a string using `codepoints-to-string.
2. From the reversed string (produced by 1. above) we get the substring after the first `&`. We do this using `substring-after()`
3. This is our result, but reversed -- we reverse it back to normal, using exactly the same logic as in step 1. above.